# Update a gallery webpage via Dropbox?

Tags: php, python, html, dropbox

I'd like to know if the following situation and scripts are at all possible:

I'm looking to have a photo-gallery (Javascript) webpage that will display in order of the latest added to the Dropbox folder (PHP or Python?).

That is, when someone adds a picture to the Dropbox folder, there is a script on the webpage that will check the Dropbox folder and then embed those images onto the webpage via the newest added and the webpage will automatically be updated.

Is it at all possible to link to a Dropbox folder via a webpage? If so, how would I best go about using scripts to automate the process of updating the webpage with new content?

Any and all help is very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You may already know this - if you go to your photo folder on the dropbox website and click on the gallery button, Dropbox displays a photo gallery, and gives you a public url you can share. 

However it doesn't sort the photos newest to oldest, and if you need to replace the Dropbox 'branding' on the page with your own, then this isn't much help. You could scrape these gallery pages to get the image urls.

Comment: Well that could be a solution - would "scraping" (or using a script) allow me to automatically update the webpage? Also, I would need to host that webpage on a seperate domain than Dropbox - is this possible?

Comment: @Amabo: You can do the scraping whenever a user requests your page, making sure it's always up to date. As far as hosting it on a different domain: Yes, it's possible, and just as easy.

Answer (score 2):

If you can install the DropBox client on the webserver then it would be simple to let it sync your folder and then iterate over the contents of the folder with a programming language (PHP, Python, .NET etc) and produce the gallery page.  This could be done every time the page is requested or as a scheduled job which recreayes a static page.  This is all dependent on you having access to install the client on your server.

Comment: nice..
how heavy is this on system resources, on a typical low-level VPS ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this : http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=15885

Answer (score 0):

You can use the (alpha) tool [autodrop](http://github.com/berkes/autodrop), wich is just that: a simple gallery frontend that uses images in Dropbox.

As said: alpha. I am still developing it, rewriting it and making it a little prettier and nicer. 
Written in Ruby, using dropbox, sinatra and HAML gems. So you will need a host that supports Ruby apps.