# Is there a purely client side (javascript) photo library that can pull photos from s3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I am looking for a javascript only photo gallery that can pull photos from an amazon S3 bucket or dropbox.

Does anything like this exist?

Basically I want to create a website for a client that does not need any server side code, and that can pull photos from a place where my client himself can upload his own photos (say amazon s3 or dropbox).

Comment: this is discussed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792472/pure-javascript-app-amazon-s3

Comment: and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522951/update-a-gallery-webpage-via-dropbox

Comment: this may also be interesting to you http://jacwright.com/556/client-side-only-javascript-amazon-s3-cms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think you'll need some server-side code to provide a link between Dropbox and S3. But if they upload directly to S3, you should be able to reference it from S3 directly or cloudfront.

Some packages that may help you on your way:

http://code.google.com/p/js3db/

https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/learnmore

http://www.andreafabrizi.it/?dropbox_uploader

http://sparkleshare.org/

http://jacwright.com/556/client-side-only-javascript-amazon-s3-cms/

Hope that helps...